# Debug python2 matplotlib with pyqt4

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt4

I have developed a little GUI with Qt4 and Matplotlib using python2.7.
It's runnable but I can't debug it because the following error appears:

```
ImportError: 
    Importing PyQt4 disabled by IPython, which has
    already imported an Incompatible QT Binding: pyside
```

The error appears as soon as I step to line 4 (from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg...)

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt4Agg')
matplotlib.rcParams['backend.qt4'] = 'PyQt4'
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
```

Any hints?

Comment: http://cyrille.rossant.net/making-pyqt4-pyside-and-ipython-work-together/

Comment: Have you tried running this without IPython first? See if that works.

Comment: You can read about this issue [here](http://cyrille.rossant.net/making-pyqt4-pyside-and-ipython-work-together/).

Comment: I can't figure out a solution.
I'm confused by the error because I just use PyQt and matplotlib with Anaconda4 x86 (Python 2.7.11) und PyCharm Community Edition.

Comment: The following command doesn't work:

from python_qt_binding import QtGui, QtCore
-->
ImportError: No module named python_qt_binding

Comment: In the project I don't use any Jupyter notebook / iPython... just pure python files. Therefore I am confused about the IPython message.